# Emit is not working on simple Token Factory

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

I'm using Hardhat 2.12.7, here's my Factory contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "./SimpleToken.sol";

contract SimpleFactory {
  event Deployed(string data);
  event TokenCreated(address indexed tokenAddress, address indexed owner);

  function createToken(
    string memory name,
    string memory symbol,
    uint256 totalSupply,
    address owner
  ) public returns (address) {
    emit Deployed("Pre new");
    SimpleToken newToken = new SimpleToken(name, symbol, totalSupply, owner);
    emit TokenCreated(address(newToken), owner);
    return address(newToken);
  }
}
```

My Token contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract SimpleToken is ERC20 {
  constructor(
    string memory name,
    string memory symbol,
    uint256 totalSupply,
    address _owner
  ) ERC20(name, symbol) {
    _mint(_owner, totalSupply);
  }
}
```

It's compiled and deployed fine, through `npx hardhat compile` and `npx hardhat run scripts/deploySimple.ts`

Like this:

```
import { ethers } from 'hardhat';
import { ContractFactory } from 'ethers';
import { SimpleToken } from '../typechain-types/contracts/SimpleToken';
import { SimpleFactory } from '../typechain-types/contracts/SimpleFactory';

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  // Deploy SimpleToken contract
  const SimpleTokenFactory: ContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    'SimpleToken'
  );
  const initialSupply = ethers.utils.parseUnits('1000000000', 18);
  const simpleToken: SimpleToken = <SimpleToken>(
    await SimpleTokenFactory.deploy(
      'MyToken',
      'MTK',
      initialSupply,
      deployer.address
    )
  );
  await simpleToken.deployed();
  console.log('SimpleToken deployed to:', simpleToken.address);

  // Deploy SimpleFactory contract
  const SimpleFactoryFactory: ContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
    'SimpleFactory'
  );
  const simpleFactory: SimpleFactory = <SimpleFactory>(
    await SimpleFactoryFactory.deploy()
  );
  await simpleFactory.deployed();
  console.log('SimpleFactory deployed to:', simpleFactory.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Then I'm using the output Factory address in my frontend app to issue a new SimpleToken through SimpleFactory. The ABI is copied from hardhat's artifacts/contracts/SimpleFactory.sol/SimpleFactory.json:

```
"abi": [
        {
            "anonymous": false,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "tokenAddress",
                    "type": "address"
                },
                {
                    "indexed": true,
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "owner",
                    "type": "address"
                }
            ],
            "name": "TokenCreated",
            "type": "event"
        },
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "string",
                    "name": "symbol",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "uint256",
                    "name": "totalSupply",
                    "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "owner",
                    "type": "address"
                }
            ],
            "name": "createToken",
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "internalType": "address",
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "address"
                }
            ],
            "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
            "type": "function"
        }
    ],
}
```

Maybe the problem is the lack of outputs in ABI for TokenCreated event?

And here's my frontend code:

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
import erc20ABI from '../../src/blockchain/abi/FactoryABI.json'
import { normalize } from '@truffle/abi-utils'
import { AbiItem } from 'web3-utils'

const NODE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8545'
const DEPLOYER_ADDRESS = '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266'
const FACTORY_ADDRESS = '0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512'

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(NODE_URL))
const abi = erc20ABI.abi
const normalizedAbi = normalize(abi)

const erc20Factory = new web3.eth.Contract(
    normalizedAbi as AbiItem[],
    FACTORY_ADDRESS
)

describe('Test erc20Factory interaction through Web3.js', () => {
    it('Creates new ERC20 token', async () => {
        const tokenName = 'MyTokenTest'
        const tokenSymbol = 'MTT'
        const kind = 'TITLE'
        const content = 'This is a good title'
        const decimals = 18

        const gas = await erc20Factory.methods
            .createToken(tokenName, tokenSymbol, 20000, DEPLOYER_ADDRESS)
            .estimateGas({ from: DEPLOYER_ADDRESS })
        console.log(`Calculated gas for operation: ${gas}`)

        const receipt = await erc20Factory.methods
            .createToken(tokenName, tokenSymbol, 20000, DEPLOYER_ADDRESS)
            .send({
                from: DEPLOYER_ADDRESS,
                gas: gas
            })

        const txReceipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(
            receipt.transactionHash
        )

        const events = await erc20Factory.getPastEvents('TokenCreated', {
            fromBlock: 0,
            toBlock: 'latest'
        })

        console.log(receipt)
        console.log(txReceipt)
        console.log(events)
    })
})

export {}
```

The output is not what I expected. Events are empty array, and receipt/txReceipt return this:

```
console.log
    {
      transactionHash: '0x72ead38bed6c4c9aa5a66fb84cbbe10f16dcc0dc9ecf0f91253414895f3d6574',
      transactionIndex: 0,
      blockHash: '0x1f2237248e1bb3efa0475b3445a6242d956f6b0175533ecb413dd734607784fa',
      blockNumber: 11,
      from: '0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266',
      to: '0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512',
      cumulativeGasUsed: 22568,
      gasUsed: 22568,
      contractAddress: null,
      logs: [],
      logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
      type: '0x2',
      status: true,
      effectiveGasPrice: 2730693045
    }
```

Even ChatGPT doesn't know what's going on here. Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wait for the transaction to be processed with `.wait()`, as right now you are not waiting for the transaction before using `getPastEvents()` - you are immediately trying to read the event but the transaction may not be finished yet.

In your code, try to implement `.wait()` like this:

```js
const receipt = await erc20Factory.methods
  .createToken(tokenName, tokenSymbol, 20000, DEPLOYER_ADDRESS)
  .send({ from: DEPLOYER_ADDRESS });

// wait for the transaction
await receipt.wait();

const events = await erc20Factory.getPastEvents('TokenCreated', {
  fromBlock: 0,
  toBlock: 'latest'
});

console.log('events:', events);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping. It seems like .wait() method is not available to the receipt object, nor I could find it in web3.js 1.x and 4.x documentation. The issue is that there's not a single event fired, and there's more than 10 blocks already there, so it didn't work for my previous attempts too, hence nothing was logged there.